# How to Move My AutoCompleteTextView Methods/Adapter to Own Class(s)

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am attempting to move some methods out of my Log-in Activity to a separate class so they can be reused by other activities. I have not been able to figure it out and would like some examples based on my usage below.

Thnx in advance.

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends FirebaseUserNet implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


    public AutoCompleteTextView inputEmail;

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    public static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inputEmail = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

    // Populate the users contacts with their given permission
        populateAutoComplete();

    }

    /**
      * TODO: Everything below here needs to be put into a separate class(s) for reuse:
      */

    public void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    public boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(inputEmail, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, ProfileQueryInterface.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQueryInterface.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        inputEmail.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: The `onRequestPermissionsResult` has to be in that class since it is the callback. Not sure you can extract that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically, you could use a CursorAdapter to remove all the Loader stuff, but anyway

---

First, I'd extract out that "may request" method.

```
public interface ContactPermissionRequester {
    boolean mayRequestContacts();
}
```

Have your activity implement that.

Then, the idea is that you just want to have a bare-bone activity and self-contain the autocomplete textview. For that, at the very least need the `Context` and the TextView. For the DB `Loader`, you also pass that.

You need to ask permissions in the Activity for these methods *I think*.

- checkSelfPermission
- shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
- requestPermissions

You could try giving the other class a `ContextCompat` instead of a `Context` and see if you can move around the permission logic.

```
public class LoginActivity extends FirebaseUserNet implements ContactPermissionRequester {

    @Override
    public boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            ...
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        inputEmail = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        AutoCompleteTextViewLoader autoloader = new AutoCompleteTextViewLoader(this, 
            inputEmail, getSupportLoaderManager());
        autoloader.populate();

    }
}
```

Almost everything else can be pulled into a new class and use the appropriate parameters / fields where necessary. The Activity is now just a Context, but it also implements that earlier interface that can request permissions.

```
public class AutoCompleteTextViewLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final AutoCompleteTextView inputEmail;
    private final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private final LoaderManager loaderManager

    private final List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    private final ContactPermissionRequester requester;

    public AutoCompleteLoader(Context context, AutoCompleteTextView textView, LoaderManager loaderManager) {
        this.mContext = context;

        this.inputEmail = textView;
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,      
                    emails);
        this.inputEmail.setAdapter(adapter);

        // This can throw a ClassCastException
        this.mRequester = (ContactPermissionRequester) context;

        this.loaderManager = loaderManager;
    }

    public List<String> getEmails() { return emails; }

    public void populate() {
        if (requester != null && !requester.mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        loadManager.initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(mContext,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, ProfileQueryInterface.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        // ArrayList not needed here
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            // Add directly to adapter
            adapter.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQueryInterface.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // Separate method was pointless
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx. So far this is looking good. However, I don't know what to put into `onRequestPermissionsResult` ... `if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//                ???????

            }
        }```

Comment: You already have that method. You can call the populate method on the other class, but that's about it without making new methods on it

Answer (score 0):

You can theorecticly extraxt all public methods, that aren't overridding their respective superclass method. That would be

```
public void populateAutoComplete()

public boolean mayRequestContacts()

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle)

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor)

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader)

private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection)
```

I would add the parameter

```
LoginActivity log_act
```

to every method, so you can give the methods a

```
this
```

pointer to the class Instance.
This way the methods have still access to everything in the class, like the fields

```
public AutoCompleteTextView inputEmail;
```

or the methods like

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer [@cricket_007 gave is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42033940/742030) on how to extract the methods [which is just an Array Adapter]. But for those who wish for the actual code that worked, I have it here below and to handle the Permission Requests, snakebar, and dialogs as required for build versions >= `API level 23`, I also implemented [Google's easypermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions).

**In Activities:**

```
public class SomeActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    . . .
    /**
      * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
      */
    public static int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        . . .
        //TODO: Fire `mayRequestContacts()` when the `AutoCompleteTextView` has focus.
        mayRequestContacts();
        . . .
    }

    public void mayRequestContacts() {
        String[] perms = { Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS };
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            // Have permission, do the thing!
        } else {
            // Ask for permissions
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.agreement_positive_text),
                    REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS, perms);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // Forward results to EasyPermissions
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            AutoCompleteTextViewLoader autoCompleteTextViewLoader = new AutoCompleteTextViewLoader(this,
                        inputEmail, getSupportLoaderManager());
            autoCompleteTextViewLoader.populate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry you choose that - You\'ll be typing a lot more.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**AutoCompleteTextEmailLoader:**

```
public class AutoCompleteTextEmailLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final AutoCompleteTextView inputEmail;
    private final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private final LoaderManager loaderManager;
    private final List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    public AutoCompleteTextEmailLoader(Context context, AutoCompleteTextView textView, LoaderManager loaderManager) {
        this.mContext = context;

        this.inputEmail = textView;
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                emails);
        this.inputEmail.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.loaderManager = loaderManager;
    }

    public void populate() {
        loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(mContext,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, ProfileQueryInterface.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        // ArrayList not needed here
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            // Add directly to adapter
            adapter.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQueryInterface.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    }
}
```